# how to clear the markers from the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, markerclusterer

i am  making a map with a leaflet slider, as the slider goes through days each markers set on the certain day are shown, so far so good , but the problem is that the markers that are put never get removed, they stay, and even if i get to the same day again it just gets over the old marker.
i have changed some things in the [original slider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) so that it works. the file as modified looks like this now

```js
L.Control.SliderControl = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'topright',
        layers: null,
        timeAttribute: 'time',
        isEpoch: false,     // whether the time attribute is seconds elapsed from epoch
        startTimeIdx: 0,    // where to start looking for a timestring
        timeStrLength: 19,  // the size of  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss - if millis are present this will be larger
        maxValue: -1,
        minValue: 0,
        showAllOnStart: false,
        markers: null,
        range: false,
        follow: false,
        alwaysShowDate : false,
        rezoom: null
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
        this._layer = this.options.layer;

    },

    extractTimestamp: function(time, options) {
        if (options.isEpoch) {
            time = (new Date(parseInt(time))).toString(); // this is local time
        }
        return time.substr(options.startTimeIdx, options.startTimeIdx + options.timeStrLength);
    },

    setPosition: function (position) {
        var map = this._map;

        if (map) {
            map.removeControl(this);
        }

        this.options.position = position;

        if (map) {
            map.addControl(this);
        }
        this.startSlider();
        return this;
    },
_updateCurrentDiv: function (startIdx, endIdx) {
this.$currentStartDiv.html(this.options.markers[startIdx].feature.properties[this.options.timeAttribute]);
        this.$currentEndDiv.html(this.options.markers[endIdx].feature.properties[this.options.timeAttribute]);
  this.$currentStartDiv = $('#slider-current .start-time', sliderContainer);
this.$currentEndDiv = $('#slider-current .end-time', sliderContainer);
this._updateCurrentDiv(0,0);
},
    onAdd: function (map) {
        this.options.map = map;

        // Create a control sliderContainer with a jquery ui slider
        var sliderContainer = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'slider', this._container);
       $(sliderContainer).append('<div id="slider-min"></div><div id="leaflet-slider" style="width:280px; inline-block; margin: 0 5px 0 5px;"></div><div id="slider-max"></div><div id="slider-current"><span class="start-time"></span>-<span class="end-time"></span></div>');
  //Prevent map panning/zooming while using the slider
        $(sliderContainer).mousedown(function () {
            map.dragging.disable();
        });
        $(document).mouseup(function () {
            map.dragging.enable();
            //Hide the slider timestamp if not range and option alwaysShowDate is set on false
            if (options.range || !options.alwaysShowDate) {
                $('#slider-timestamp').html('');
            }
        });

        var options = this.options;
        this.options.markers = [];

        //If a layer has been provided: calculate the min and max values for the slider
        if (this._layer) {
            var index_temp = 0;
            this._layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                options.markers[index_temp] = layer;
                ++index_temp;
            });
            options.maxValue = index_temp - 1;
            this.options = options;
        } else {
            console.log("Error: You have to specify a layer via new SliderControl({layer: your_layer});");
        }
        return sliderContainer;
  $('#slider-min', sliderContainer).html(this.options.markers[this.options.minValue].feature.properties[this.options.timeAttribute]);
        $('#slider-max', sliderContainer).html(this.options.markers[this.options.maxValue].feature.properties[this.options.timeAttribute]);
    },

    onRemove: function (map) {
        //Delete all markers which where added via the slider and remove the slider div
        for (i = this.options.minValue; i < this.options.maxValue; i++) {
            map.removeLayer(this.options.markers[i]);
        }
        $('#leaflet-slider').remove();
    },

    startSlider: function () {
  
        _options = this.options;
        _extractTimestamp = this.extractTimestamp
        var index_start = _options.minValue;
        if(_options.showAllOnStart){
            index_start = _options.maxValue;
            if(_options.range) _options.values = [_options.minValue,_options.maxValue];
            else _options.value = _options.maxValue;
        }
        $("#leaflet-slider").slider({
            range: _options.range,
            value: _options.value,
            values: _options.values,
            min: _options.minValue,
            max: _options.maxValue,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (e, ui) {
    var markall = new  L.markerClusterGroup();
    //var markall = new L.layerGroup();
                var map = _options.map;
                var fg = L.featureGroup();
                if(!!_options.markers[ui.value]) {
                    // If there is no time property, this line has to be removed (or exchanged with a different property)
                    if(_options.markers[ui.value].feature !== undefined) {
                        if(_options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties[_options.f ]){
                            if(_options.markers[ui.value]) $('#slider-timestamp').html(
                                _extractTimestamp(_options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
                        }else {
                            console.error("Time property "+ _options.timeAttribute +" not found in data");
                        }
                    }else {
                        // set by leaflet Vector Layers
                        if(_options.markers [ui.value].options[_options.timeAttribute]){
                            if(_options.markers[ui.value]){ $('#slider-timestamp').html(
                                _extractTimestamp(_options.markers[ui.value].options[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
        $('#start').html(_extractTimestamp(_options.markers[ui.values[0]].options[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
       $('#end').html( _extractTimestamp(_options.markers[ui.values[1]].options[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
       
        }
                        }else {
                            console.error("Time property "+ _options.timeAttribute +" not found in data");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    var i;
                    // clear markers
       markall.clearLayers();
       map.removeLayer(markall);
       //alert("test");
                    
                    if(_options.range){
       
                        // jquery ui using range
                        for (i = ui.values[0]; i <= ui.values[1]; i++){
                           if(_options.markers[i]) {
                           //    map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                               fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
          markall.addLayer(daygroups[i]);
                           }
        
                        }
       map.addLayer(markall);
                    }else if(_options.follow){
       
                        for (i = ui.value - _options.follow + 1; i <= ui.value ; i++) {
                            if(_options.markers[i]) {
                              //  map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                                fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                            
                           markall.addLayer(daygroups[i]);
       }
                           }
         map.addLayer(markall);
                    }else{
       
                        for (i = _options.minValue; i <= ui.value ; i++) {
                            if(_options.markers[i]) {
                               // map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                                fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
        markall.addLayer(daygroups[i]);
                            }
                           
                           }
         map.addLayer(markall);
                    }
                };
                if(_options.rezoom) {
                    map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds(), {
                        maxZoom: _options.rezoom
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        if (!_options.range && _options.alwaysShowDate) {
            $('#slider-timestamp').html(_extractTimeStamp(_options.markers[index_start].feature.properties[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
        }
        for (i = _options.minValue; i <= index_start; i++) {
            //_options.map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
        }
  
    }
});

L.control.sliderControl = function (options) {
 $('span').show();
    return new L.Control.SliderControl(options);
};
```

and as you can see, i tried multiple times emptying the cluster and the map, but same thing seems to happen ,markers are not removed, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your case?

Comment: not a fiddle but here is the site http://85.112.78.45:8000/reporting/plot_point2

Comment: Don't you need to fix the error that is coming out of line 206 in the slider JS first? `map.removeLayer(markall);` markall is undefined at that point in the code.